# Using intersection of Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

The question was given to me as follows:
Let $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ be increasing functions on $[a,b]$.

(a) Prove that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ is increasing. (I did this using inequalities)

(b) Let $f \in \Re_{\alpha_1}[a,b] \cap \Re_{\alpha_2}[a,b].$ Prove that $f \in  \Re_{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}[a,b]$ and $$\int_a^b f d(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = \int_a^b f d\alpha_1 + \int_a^b f d\alpha_2$$

This is where I'm lost now. I know since $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ is increasing that I can use some things I know but I'm not sure which. I am thinking I can maybe use the Riemann condition? Since I know that $f \in \Re_{\alpha_1}[a,b] \cap \Re_{\alpha_2}[a,b]$ that means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \varepsilon$. Can I now work with this? Or is another concept more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Using Riemann sums: $S(f, P, T, \alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = S(f, P, T, \alpha_1) + S(f, P, T, \alpha_2)$ for any partition $P$ and any choice of valid tags $T$ for $P.$ QED

As for Darboux's sums, prove that $U(f, P, \alpha_1 + \alpha_2) \leq U(f, P, \alpha_1) + U(f, P, \alpha_2)$ and that $U(f, P, \alpha_1) + L(f, P, \alpha_2) \leq L(f, P, \alpha_1 + \alpha_2).$ And then use an $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$-argument

Comment: Is this a known property? I may be nitpicking here, but at this point in the book, we have not yet learned this concept (but I have in class).

Comment: Well, there are several different definitions of Riemann integral. I am taking the one via Riemann sums (if you are taking Darboux's or Cauchy's approach, then let me know).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any actual name put to what I have learned so far. But the major concepts involve upper and lower bounds and the Riemann condition. Is it possible to do using these?

Comment: That is Darboux's approach and the upper and lower sums are known (also) as Darboux's sums. Let me amend the answer.

Comment: I'm actually having a bit of a difficulty about how to actually prove those statements

Comment: I think they are actually equalities. Write down definitions and it should come forward; recall that once P is fixed, the suprema and infima are fixed too...